# Passing multiple SQL statements in C# and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I want to be able to use an existing stored procedure that requires the existence of a temp table. I was attempting to create the temp table then run the stored procedure that requires 2 parameters. What I have is below but I don't know how to pass the parameters and make it work.

```
var _sql = @"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ID') IS NOT NULL
                DROP TABLE #ID
CREATE TABLE #ID (ID_ID INT, ID_NUMBER INT)
EXEC dbo.imc_generate_id @Formattype, @user_id";

var _result = RepositoryContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(_sql);
```

I want to be able to create the temp table then run the stored procedure with the `@Formattype` and `@user_id` parameters.

How do I pass the parameters here if I am running multiple SQL commands?

Comment: What's the connection between the temporary table and the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand%28System.String,System.Object[]%29)

Like this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.Posts SET Rating = 5 WHERE Author = @author", new SqlParameter("@author", userSuppliedAuthor));
```

Did you try this?

Edit:

For multiple parameters:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sql query", new SqlParameter("@author", userSuppliedAuthor), new SqlParameter("@author", userSuppliedAuthor));
```

You can add more SqlParameter objects to the code.